# Correct way to setup a model for a form with different input text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to setup a model for a form but I'm struggling to understand how I should set the models for capturing the proper information that I want.
(info: I'm user webApp with RazorPages)

I want to achieve this, with every "comment" being a different textbox in which the user can insert text:
[image]

Then later I want to save all this into a sql server database so I can later retrieve the comments that were added by other users.

I have created this in the Expenditure Model file:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(int projectId)
{
    Project = await _db.GetProjectDataAsync(projectId);

    var calculations = await _db.GetCalculationByProjectIdAsync(projectId);

    WipCommentCalculation = new WipCommentCalculation
    {
        Calculations = new Calculations
        {
            BillableLabor = calculations.BillableLabor,
            BillableNonLabor = calculations.BillableNonLabor,
            BillableSubcontractor = calculations.BillableSubcontractor,
            UnbilledLabor = calculations.UnbilledLabor,
            UnbilledNonLabor = calculations.UnbilledNonLabor,
            UnbilledSubcontractor = calculations.UnbilledSubcontractor,
            BillingHoldLabor = calculations.BillingHoldLabor,
            BillingHoldNonLabor = calculations.BillingHoldNonLabor,
            BillingHoldSubcontractor = calculations.BillingHoldSubcontractor
        },
        Comments = null,
        ProjectId = projectId
    };
}
```

And I have this in the view:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-control">
    <h2>Expenditures</h2>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Billable</th>
                <th>Unbilled</th>
                <th>Billing Hold</th>
                <th>Project Accountant explanation</th>
                <th>Project Manager Accountant comments</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Labor</td> 
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillableLabor:0,0.00}")</td> 
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledLabor:0,0.00}")</td> 
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillingHoldLabor:0,0.00}")</td> 
                <td><input asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments.PALaborComment"/></td>
                <td><input asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments.PMLaborComment"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Non-Labor</td> 
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillableNonLabor:0,0.00}")</td> 
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledNonLabor:0,0.00}")</td> 
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillingHoldNonLabor:0,0.00}")</td> 
                <td><input asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments.PANonLaborComment"/></td>
                <td><input asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments.PMNonLaborComment"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SubContractor</td>
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillableSubcontractor:0,0.00}")</td>
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledSubcontractor:0,0.00}")</td>
                <td>@($"{Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillingHoldSubcontractor:0,0.00}")</td>
                <td><input asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments.PASubContractorComment"/></td>
                <td><input asp-for="WipCommentCalculation.Comments.PMSubcontractorComment"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Totals</td> 
                <td>@($"{(Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillableLabor + Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillableNonLabor + Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillableSubcontractor):0,0.00}")</td>
                <td>@($"{(Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledLabor + Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledNonLabor + Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.UnbilledSubcontractor):0,0.00}")</td>
                <td>@($"{(Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillingHoldLabor + Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillingHoldNonLabor + Model.WipCommentCalculation.Calculations.BillingHoldSubcontractor):0,0.00}")</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

These are the models:

```
public class WipCommentCalculation
{
    public Calculations Calculations{ get; set; }

    public CommentModel Comments { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId{ get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Calculations
{
    public decimal BillableLabor { get; set; }

    public decimal BillableNonLabor { get; set; }

    public decimal BillableSubcontractor { get; set; }

    public decimal UnbilledLabor { get; set; }

    public decimal UnbilledNonLabor { get; set; }

    public decimal UnbilledSubcontractor { get; set; }

    public decimal BillingHoldLabor { get; set; }

    public decimal BillingHoldNonLabor { get; set; }

    public decimal BillingHoldSubcontractor { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CommentModel
{
    public string PALaborComment { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PANonLaborComment { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PASubContractorComment { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PMLaborComment { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PMNonLaborComment { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PMSubcontractorComment { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

But I don't know if the way I'm setting it up is correct, can I get a critique on this and a better way to do it? I can also add the github repo if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, your code works fine to received `WipCommentCalculation` model which is filled with Comments property. And what you did has been a better way... Do you have advanced requirement?

Comment: @Rena Hello, thank you, I just wasn't sure my was of doing it was the correct one, I don't have a requirement to do it differently but I wanted to do it properly to internalize it as it has to be, so I was looking for better practices or other examples (I'm self taught so I doubt of myself a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest way to represent a table is to use a model that has a List of objects, where the object has all the properties of the table.

```
public class TableModel
{
    List<Row> rows { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

the TableModel in addition can have other properties that you might need.

With this method you can have a dynamic model that can adapt to an infinite number of rows, and can be easily updated.

Comment: But in my case, every row hasa different data, is not something I can easily traverse with a foreach for example, I have a finite table that I need to represent

Comment: what i understand from your example is that you have the first 3 columns that contatins a float, and the last 2 that contains a string, in this case the method i illustrated is perfectly feasable

Comment: And how would I then represent the fields? being that I need to operate with them and later send them into a database? can you maybe point me to an example of this? should I traverse with a foreach?